# I want to disable Cash on delivery based on product tag in woocommerce Checkout Page

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'cod_enable_manager' );


function cod_enable_manager( $available_gateways ) {
   if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) &&( is_product_tag( 'Overseas' ) )) {
      unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
   } 
   return $available_gateways;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove cash option at checkout you need to get the terms first before you check.

something like: `$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_tag' );`

Then you can run checks and if any match selected items in cart at checkout by product tag then hide your gateway.